# How to group strings according to first half in R?

Tags: r

I have an R code that looks like this:

```
files <- list.files(get_directory())
files <- files[grepl("*.dat$", files)]
files
```

where `get_directory()` is a function I wrote that returns the current directory. So, I'm getting all the files with extension `.dat` in the directory that I want. But, my files are named as follows:

```
2^5-3^3-18-simul.dat
2^5-3^3-18-uniform.dat
2^7-3^4-33-simul.dat
2^7-3^4-33-uniform.dat
...
```

So, now I want to creates groups of 2 according to the first part, so I want `2^5-3^3-18-simul.dat` and `2^5-3^3-18-uniform.dat` to be one group, the other two files one group etc. While at a later stage, I need to loop through all the groups, and use the two files that are in the same group. Since, the filenames returned are already sorted, I do not think I need some fancy pattern matching here, I just need to get to group the elements of the string vector two by two as mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to create a grouping variable to split the 'files'

```
split(files, sub("-[a-z].*", "", files))
#$`2^5-3^3-18`
#[1] "2^5-3^3-18-simul.dat"   "2^5-3^3-18-uniform.dat"

#$`2^7-3^4-33`
#[1] "2^7-3^4-33-simul.dat"   "2^7-3^4-33-uniform.dat"
```

#### data

```
files <-  c("2^5-3^3-18-simul.dat", "2^5-3^3-18-uniform.dat", 
             "2^7-3^4-33-simul.dat", "2^7-3^4-33-uniform.dat")
```